# CSS table: fixed header and same column width for <td> and <th>

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want a pure CSS solution with a fixed table header and same column width for `<th>` and `<td>` with different content. I have taken an example and modified it to get column with different content: http://jsfiddle.net/jd72op9n/4/

```
table tbody,table thead {
  display: block; /* comment to get same column with*/
}
table tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

It seems that I cannot have both:

1. If take http://jsfiddle.net/jd72op9n/4/ I get a fixed header but the columns for th and td are not the same.
2. If I remove "display: block", I get the correct column but not fixed header.

Do you have a solution to get both?

Comment: if m not wrong, you might want this http://jsfiddle.net/jd72op9n/9/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only way is to strictly specify the width of the cells like this:

```
table th, table td{
  width: 80px;
}
tbody{
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Please try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd72op9n/7/)

And if you want to change width to certain cell, for example the 4th with the long text, you can add this css rule:

```
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4){
  width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: It does only works with the small hight. If I increase it and make the browser height smaller the table header is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/patelnirpendra/2bs886p0/

css :

```
table tbody,table thead {
  display: block;
}

table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I see no fixed table header

Comment: You just need to add that for the fixed header
`tbody {
  height:140px;
  overflow:auto;
}`